# how to access textbox value to code behind using asp.net Content Page?

Tags: asp.net

i have a textbox and a button in my aspx file,i want to get the textbox value to code behind while clicking the button,I implemented this before,but now iam using asp:content pages,but now i cant get the value to codebehind

my aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test1.test" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<body>
<div>
<input type="text" runat="server" id="abc" />
<asp:Button 
 ID="Button1" 
 runat="server" 
 Text="Search" 
class="btn"
OnClick="Button1_Click"
/>
 </div>
</body>
</asp:Content>
```

My aspx.cs

```
protected void Button1_Click(Object sender,
                         System.EventArgs e)
 {
        string txtboxvalue = Request.Form["abc"];
 }
```

but i cant get the textbox value in button click.

Comment: I'm suprised that you've not tried `abc.Value` or use a `TextBox` and `abc.Text`

Answer (score 0):

Your control doesn't have a name, so it doesn't get POSTed in the form that you can read it as `Request.Form["abc"]`. WebForms will generate its name, something like `master00$formName$abc`. You can check this in the HTML source, but it may be different per request or change after you add more controls on the page. So you should not use this field when it's autogenerated.

Either give it a name:

```
<input type="text" runat="server" id="abc" name="abc" />
```

Or, because it's `runat="server"` and has an `id`, you can simply access it from code behind:

```
string textBoxValue = abc.Value;
```

Comment: It's not a `TextBox` so he needs `abc.Value`

Comment: @Tim I though WebForms recognized the `<input type="text" runat="server" id="foo" />` as a TextBox and generates a `TextBox foo` member. Guess I shouldn't type from memory, thanks. :P

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already given runat to your input control,

```
 <input type="text" runat="server" id="abc" />
```

You can access the value of text like this

```
  string txtboxvalue = abc.Value;
```

//Here no need of using Request.Form since input is now a server control